# Como inserir dados em outro banco com Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, trigger, linked-server

Boa tarde!

Como faço para criar um gatilho que utilize um Linked Server para inserir os dados do INSERTED em outra tabela que fica em outro banco, este em outro servidor?

Tentando Exemplificar:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TESTE] ON [TABELA_XYZ]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LINKSERVER.BD.DBO.TABELA_ABC (CAMPO1, CAMPO2)
  SELECT CAMPOA, CAMPOB FROM INSERTED
END
```

Com esse mesmo "trigger" já consegui inserir os dados dessa tabela em outra tabela do mesmo servidor/banco, porém quando tento utilizar o Linked Server está dando esse erro:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "DMPAP8" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "DMPAP8" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

Os dois bancos são SQL Server 2012, porém estão em servidores diferentes, ServidorA e ServidorB, e eu preciso copiar do servidor B para o A e da tabela XYZ para a ABC.

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.

Comment: para sincronizar tabelas entre instâncias diferentes há outros métodos menos arriscados do que procedimento de gatilho que utilize vinculação de servidores (_linked server_). Avalie, por exemplo, o uso de algum tipo de replicação ou mesmo um _job_ que faça a sincronização, de tempos em tempos.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 2):

Boas,
Uma vez que os 2 Servidores são SQL Server 2012, porquê você não usa o SQL Server Native Client ao invés do OLE DB. O Ole DB trabalho com recursos mais generalizados de vários motores de Base de Dados. Bem diferente do Native Client, que usa recursos nativos do SQL Server.
Para além disso, verifique a configuração na seguinte imagem, e a inactive se não precisar dela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro assegure-se que o "Coordenador de transações distribuídas" está sendo executado em todos os servidores:

- Aperte <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>;
- Digite `services.msc`;
- Aperte <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- Inicie o "Coordenador de transações distribuídas" caso ele não esteja sendo executado.

Se a aplicação cliente não estiver na mesma máquina que o servidor execute os seguintes passos no servidor:

- Aperte <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>;
- Digite `comexp.msc`;
- Aperte <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- Na árvore do lado esquerdo navegue para <kbd>Serviços de Componente| Computadores | Meu Computador | Coordenador de transações distribuídas</kbd>;
- Clique o botão direito em "DTC Local" e em "Propriedades";
- Vá para a aba "Segurança";
- Garanta que as opções "Acesso DTC de Rede", "Permitir Clientes Remotos", "Permitir Entrada" e "Permitir Saída" estejam marcadas;
- Clique em "Aplicar";
- Reinicie o serviço no `services.msc`;
- Talvez seja necessário reiniciar o servidor;

No cliente faça o mesmo procedimento acima e garanta as opções "Acesso DTC de Rede", "Permitir Entrada" e "Permitir Saída". Reinicie o serviço e o servidor, se for necessário.

No "SQL Server Service Manager" o serviço "Coordenador de transações distribuídas" deve estar executando.

---

**Referências:**

- [**The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/7172223f-acbe-4472-8cdf-feec80fd2e64/the-partner-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remotenetwork-transactions?forum=adodotnetdataproviders);
- [**The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10131344/3388148).